# Did the layout process change in Android 7?

Tags: android, layout, android-7.0-nougat

In a custom class that extends View,
the sequence of calls on pre Android 7 (devices and emulator)

```
onMeasure
onLayout (changed = true)
onMeasure
onLayout (changed = false)
onDraw
...
```

now the **emulator** with 7.0

```
onMeasure
onMeasure
onLayout (changed = true)
onDraw
...
```

there is no "confirmation" onLayout call and it is measured twice ?!

I can't find any documentation as to why or how it changed, can anyone point me in the right direction or explain it here ?